# words around the verb "record"

Tags: word-choice, collocations

Teachers will record a play performed by students, make DVDs, and give them to the students.

Can I say

> Teachers are planning to record the show **and make a DVD** to give copies of it to us.

or

> Teachers are planning to record the show **on DVD** and give them to us.

?

The speaker, a hero of my short story, is one of the student performer and he is writing an e-mail to his friend.

My dictionary say you can say "I recorded the TV show on tape", but how about DVDs? And in this case it's not TV program. How can you say when you are recording something by your camcorder?

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be '...and give _copies_ to us' (_a DVD_ is singular and _them_ is plural). But a student writing an email might not express himself very clearly.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you so much!  To choose correct articles is my another problem, but I think I understand better now.

Comment: I didn't mean _its copies_, but _copies [of it]_.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, OK! I didn't know the difference of "its copies" and "copies of it." Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, either would be acceptable. The difference between the two is more technical, and many English speakers would not care about the difference.

"Record onto.." a medium really means that the recording is *directly* recorded to that medium. For example, "Edison recorded sound onto wax cylinders" is a true statement.

There were devices that directly recorded onto DVD - 'DVD Recorders' were briefly thought to be the logical replacement for domestic VHS recorders. However, the technology was very short-lived as DVRs quickly appeared that could store recorded shows onto a hard disk, and many users found recording straight to DVD to be unreliable due to the index having to be constantly re-written to a different part of the disc as recordings were appended. To the best of my knowlege, no video cameras recorded straight to DVD, and if they did I imagine they would have terrible problems with the disc skipping as the camera moved.

What your teacher is probably going to do is record the show using a camera with some kind of internal, solid-state storage, and then use a computer to write the video file onto a DVD. For that reason, your first example is the most technically correct.

Comment: Sony "HandyCam" camcorder did record more or less directly on mini-DVDs.  I didn't use mine long enough to vouch for the reliability - but they were out there.  The phrase "Record on tape" was very common in the VCR days and adapted for DVDs - e.g. "I'm going to burn this movie on DVD" a very common phrase.